# Stop user-selection in Bootstrap navbar

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, user-experience

I would like to prevent user-selection to be possible on a Boostrap `navbar`, such as :

http://getbootstrap.com/examples/navbar-fixed-top/

**How to stop user-selection ?**

I tried `user-select: none;` but it fails if you do CTRL-A.

*Note : I don't want to stop user to copy text on the page, but I want to provide better user experience by avoiding selection of navbar elements.*

Comment: Are you using browser prefixes? Chrome certainly requires it. `-webkit-user-select: none;` works for me.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could do it like this:

### Bootply - [DEMO](http://www.bootply.com/J8Y1qyNrg8)

```
.navbar {
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  -o-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;    
}
```

**More Info:**

> [Mozilla MDN user-select](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/user-select)
>
> [CSS-Tricks user-select](http://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/u/user-select/)

## Solution 2: Disable user selection when press CTRL+A

You could also do it by set the `::selection` background color to `none`

### Bootply - [DEMO](http://www.bootply.com/vBac2TYmYr)

```
div.navbar *::-moz-selection {
    background: none !important;
}
div.navbar *::selection {
    background: none !important;
}
.navbar {
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  -o-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;    
}
```

Comment: Try CTRL+A in your demo: the `navbar`'s links will be selected.

Comment: That works for Chrome.  When I tried in Firefox it didn't work when trying to use CTRL+A.  It still selected the text.  Also failed in IE using CTRL+A and by selecting the text below and moving the cursor up to the nav.  This looks like a good start, but buyer beware, so to speak.

Answer (score 19):

In bootstrap 4.5 and above, you can just use `class="user-select-none"`